# Why aren't my columns maintaining height for small screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I have a three columns that stack when the screen size is reduced. At full screen these columns have background images and padding-bottom 25%. As soon as they stack the height of the div is reduced and the background image gets cut off. I have tried media queries to prevent this but to no avail.

```css
.brdcol {
  padding-bottom: 25%;
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.img3 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="col-sm-4 brdcol img1" href="watersports.html"> Water Sports</a>
<a class="col-sm-4 brdcol img2" href="football.html"> Football</a>
<a class="col-sm-4 brdcol img3" href="#"> Camping</a>
```

See photos of pre and post breakpoint:

[image: pre breakpoint]

[image: post breakpoint]

I also noticed that when viewing the page in browser, zooming out doesnt change the size of the div which hold the background image.

Comment: If you could provide a sample that shows the issue happening, someone would probably quickly be able to help you (for example in jsfiddle).

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes bootstrap. I will look at jsfiddle now.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the behavior you see for the stacked layout is what I'd expect with 25% padding. It's the other layout that's misbehaving.

It's not a standard pattern to put layout classes on content elements like anchors. I'd encourage you to use divs or other structural elements for layout, and put your links inside those.

```css
.brdcol {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.img3 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800);
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="brdcol img1" href="watersports.html"> Water</a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="brdcol img2" href="football.html"> Football</a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="brdcol img3" href="#"> Camping</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this display to show columns and apply this CSS on images and just change the display on different devices. I hope your problem will be resolved.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
}

.img1, .img3, .img3 {
  background-image: url(http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/riceracer_assets/img/car_2.png);
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.brdcol {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Custom grid CSS isn't a good idea when using a library like Bootstrap, which already provides layout mechanisms.